# how to add headers to a selected data from bigger data frame?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, datatables

I'm learning pandas and I have a DataFrame (from CSV) that I need to filter. The original DataFrame looks like this:

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+
| Header1  |  Header2  |   Header3   |
| Value 1  |  A        |      B      |
| Value 1  |  A        |      B      |
| Value 2  |  C        |      D      |
| Value 1  |  A        |      B      |
| Value 3  |  B        |      E      |
| Value 3  |  B        |      E      |
| Value 2  |  C        |      D      |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Then, I select the new data with this code:

```
dataframe.header1.value_counts()
```

output:

```
Value 1 -- 3
Value 2 -- 2
Value 3 -- 2
dtype: int64
```

So, I need to add headers to this selection and output something like this

```
Values     Count
Value 1 -- 3
Value 2 -- 2
Value 3 -- 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.Series.value_counts` returns a Series, where the Index is all unique values in the Series calling the method. `reset_index` is what you want to make it a `DataFrame`, and we can use the `rename` methods to get the column labels correct.

```
(df.Header1.value_counts()
   .rename('Count')        # Series name becomes column label for counts
   .rename_axis('Values')  # Index name becomes column label for unique values.
   .reset_index()          # Series -> DataFrame
)

#    Values  Count
#0  Value_1      3
#1  Value_2      2
#2  Value_3      2
```

Comment: The solition goes perfect, but I need to make a bar graphic, and the bar name are from # column. How can I change the bar name or add name to each bar  ?

Comment: @Neron It's a bit unclear to me, but I think you just want to not `.reset_index` then you can `.plot().bar()`